# Simulate proximity sensor

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Is there a possibility to simulate use of **proximity sensor** using iOS simulator on Xcode 9.3?
Simulator version: 10.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. You can't simulate with simulator.